# CNAME for main website, to load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancer, cname

We are wanting to use an AWS provided load balancer for our main website.

The issue we are running into is that it appears to want us to refer to it by CNAME, which seems to cause problems in the DNS, if we choose to have `@ CNAME lb.address`.

We could just assign the CNAME to 'www.examplesite.com', but then I am not sure how we tell traffic coming to 'examplesite.com' to go to 'www.examplesite.com'.

We are currently using GoDaddy for the DNS, but open to using AWS's 'Route 53' if it could help?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please give more details.

Comment: A given AWS LB has a dynamic IP and that's why you need to reference it by its name and not its IP address. So the DNS will be set to the CNAME.